# DOM scroll (touchmove) event, how to find which element scrolls

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Here is the somewhat contrived code:

```
 function h (evt) {
   if(evt.target.nodeName !=== 'POPUP') {
       evt.preventDefault()
   }
 }
 window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', h, false)
 window.addEventListener('wheel', h, false)
```

What it tries to achieve here is to prevent all other scrolling on the page, except inside popup when popup is opened.
But this doesn't work because `evt.target` contains element currently pointed by mouse rather than one that actually scrolled. So either the whole page would be scrolled or just popup conents, but in both cases `evt.target` will point to some button inside popup.

But the idea is to get what got actually scrolled now, page body or popup.

https://jsfiddle.net/zr9hjL4s/1/

Comment: show working jsfiddle or codepen example for quick solution.

Comment: `e.stopPropagation()` should do the trick without knowing which element is scrolled.

Comment: @Teemu, but in order to determine whether to stop propagation or preventdefault, you first need to know if you should, which means you need to know which element is being scrolled.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the trick here is to work altogether with the js dynamic code to stopPropagation and preventDefault behavior of scrolling plus the css code to hide the overflow capability that enables the browser scrolling over elements. So to consider here first, is once the modal is opened You need to disable the scrolling over the whole page (body) in this case, not sure how your page is constructed in real scenario but in this case we have a classical modal opened through js by adding the state kind of modal-open and removing the class once we close the modal. The modal is opened by using the js function openModal. In the example provided, I run this function once the whole js code is executed. So the modal will prompt immediately. Also check that the css rule overflow-y is used inside the modal content to let the "inside" be scroll-able.

Depends on your needs. You can play with the code and adapt with the requirement You have, but this code has saved me several times in the past. :D Hope this helps.

```js
const modalContainer = document.getElementById('modal-container');
const modalContent = document.getElementById('modal-content');

function openModal() {
  modalContainer.style.display = 'block';
  document.body.classList.add('modal-open');
  document.body.addEventListener('scroll', disableScroll);
}

function closeModal() {
  modalContainer.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.classList.remove('modal-open');
  document.body.removeEventListener('scroll', disableScroll);
}

modalContainer.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (event.target === modalContainer) {
    closeModal();
  }
});

// Optional: Close the modal when the Escape key is pressed
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  if (event.key === 'Escape') {
    closeModal();
  }
});

function disableScroll(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
}

openModal()
```

```css
.modal-container {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 9999;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.modal-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-width: 80%;
  max-height: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow-y: auto; 
}

body.modal-open {
  overflow: hidden; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Modal Window</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Your page content goes here -->
  <div>
  What it tries to achieve here is to prevent all other scrolling on the page, except inside popup when popup is opened. But this doesn't work because evt.target contains element currently pointed by mouse rather than one that actually scrolled. So either the whole page would be scrolled or just popup conents, but in both cases evt.target will point to some button inside popup.

But the idea is to get what got actually scrolled now, page body or popup.<br/>
What it tries to achieve here is to prevent all other scrolling on the page, except inside popup when popup is opened. But this doesn't work because evt.target contains element currently pointed by mouse rather than one that actually scrolled. So either the whole page would be scrolled or just popup conents, but in both cases evt.target will point to some button inside popup.

But the idea is to get what got actually scrolled now, page body or popup.
   
   <br/>
   What it tries to achieve here is to prevent all other scrolling on the page, except inside popup when popup is opened. But this doesn't work because evt.target contains element currently pointed by mouse rather than one that actually scrolled. So either the whole page would be scrolled or just popup conents, but in both cases evt.target will point to some button inside popup.

But the idea is to get what got actually scrolled now, page body or popup.<br/>
What it tries to achieve here is to prevent all other scrolling on the page, except inside popup when popup is opened. But this doesn't work because evt.target contains element currently pointed by mouse rather than one that actually scrolled. So either the whole page would be scrolled or just popup conents, but in both cases evt.target will point to some button inside popup.

But the idea is to get what got actually scrolled now, page body or popup.

  </div>
  <!-- Modal Container -->
  <div id="modal-container" class="modal-container">
    <div id="modal-content" class="modal-content">
      <!-- Your modal content goes here -->
      <h2>Modal Window</h2>
      <p>Scroll me!!!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin euismod purus ut facilisis elementum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin euismod purus ut facilisis elementum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin euismod purus ut facilisis elementum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin euismod purus ut facilisis elementum.<br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin euismod purus ut facilisis elementum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin euismod purus ut facilisis elementum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin euismod purus ut facilisis elementum.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin euismod purus ut facilisis elementum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin euismod purus ut facilisis elementum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin euismod purus ut facilisis elementum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin euismod purus ut facilisis elementum.<br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin euismod purus ut facilisis elementum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin euismod purus ut facilisis elementum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin euismod purus ut facilisis elementum.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin euismod purus ut facilisis elementum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin euismod purus ut facilisis elementum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin euismod purus ut facilisis elementum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin euismod purus ut facilisis elementum.<br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin euismod purus ut facilisis elementum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin euismod purus ut facilisis elementum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin euismod purus ut facilisis elementum.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin euismod purus ut facilisis elementum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin euismod purus ut facilisis elementum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin euismod purus ut facilisis elementum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin euismod purus ut facilisis elementum.<br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin euismod purus ut facilisis elementum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin euismod purus ut facilisis elementum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin euismod purus ut facilisis elementum.</p>
      <!-- End of modal content -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- End of page content -->
  <div>
  What it tries to achieve here is to prevent all other scrolling on the page, except inside popup when popup is opened. But this doesn't work because evt.target contains element currently pointed by mouse rather than one that actually scrolled. So either the whole page would be scrolled or just popup conents, but in both cases evt.target will point to some button inside popup.

But the idea is to get what got actually scrolled now, page body or popup.<br/>
What it tries to achieve here is to prevent all other scrolling on the page, except inside popup when popup is opened. But this doesn't work because evt.target contains element currently pointed by mouse rather than one that actually scrolled. So either the whole page would be scrolled or just popup conents, but in both cases evt.target will point to some button inside popup.

But the idea is to get what got actually scrolled now, page body or popup.
   
   <br/>
   What it tries to achieve here is to prevent all other scrolling on the page, except inside popup when popup is opened. But this doesn't work because evt.target contains element currently pointed by mouse rather than one that actually scrolled. So either the whole page would be scrolled or just popup conents, but in both cases evt.target will point to some button inside popup.

But the idea is to get what got actually scrolled now, page body or popup.<br/>
What it tries to achieve here is to prevent all other scrolling on the page, except inside popup when popup is opened. But this doesn't work because evt.target contains element currently pointed by mouse rather than one that actually scrolled. So either the whole page would be scrolled or just popup conents, but in both cases evt.target will point to some button inside popup.

But the idea is to get what got actually scrolled now, page body or popup.

  <br/>
   What it tries to achieve here is to prevent all other scrolling on the page, except inside popup when popup is opened. But this doesn't work because evt.target contains element currently pointed by mouse rather than one that actually scrolled. So either the whole page would be scrolled or just popup conents, but in both cases evt.target will point to some button inside popup.

But the idea is to get what got actually scrolled now, page body or popup.<br/>
What it tries to achieve here is to prevent all other scrolling on the page, except inside popup when popup is opened. But this doesn't work because evt.target contains element currently pointed by mouse rather than one that actually scrolled. So either the whole page would be scrolled or just popup conents, but in both cases evt.target will point to some button inside popup.

But the idea is to get what got actually scrolled now, page body or popup.

 <br/>
   What it tries to achieve here is to prevent all other scrolling on the page, except inside popup when popup is opened. But this doesn't work because evt.target contains element currently pointed by mouse rather than one that actually scrolled. So either the whole page would be scrolled or just popup conents, but in both cases evt.target will point to some button inside popup.

But the idea is to get what got actually scrolled now, page body or popup.<br/>
What it tries to achieve here is to prevent all other scrolling on the page, except inside popup when popup is opened. But this doesn't work because evt.target contains element currently pointed by mouse rather than one that actually scrolled. So either the whole page would be scrolled or just popup conents, but in both cases evt.target will point to some button inside popup.

But the idea is to get what got actually scrolled now, page body or popup.

 <br/>
   What it tries to achieve here is to prevent all other scrolling on the page, except inside popup when popup is opened. But this doesn't work because evt.target contains element currently pointed by mouse rather than one that actually scrolled. So either the whole page would be scrolled or just popup conents, but in both cases evt.target will point to some button inside popup.

But the idea is to get what got actually scrolled now, page body or popup.<br/>
What it tries to achieve here is to prevent all other scrolling on the page, except inside popup when popup is opened. But this doesn't work because evt.target contains element currently pointed by mouse rather than one that actually scrolled. So either the whole page would be scrolled or just popup conents, but in both cases evt.target will point to some button inside popup.

But the idea is to get what got actually scrolled now, page body or popup.

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/web20opensource/14zp6btL/1/

Comment: Using stop propagation here is a bad practice and should be avoided, as for example some framework might want to use the propagation to keep track of what's going on

Comment: Thanks, however this only disables the body scroll, there could be parents between the modal and the body that are scrollable and need their scroll disabled too.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. Will take note and have it in mind next time I came across with this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the overflow property of the parents to prevent scrolling?

Check out this approach:

```js
// Store previous overflow styles

const previousParentNodesOverflowStylesMap = new Map();

// Show/hide popup click handlers

document.getElementById("showPopup").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
  disablePopupParentNodesOverflow();
});

document.getElementById("hidePopup").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
  restorePopupParentNodesOverflow();
});

// Parents overflow CSS property management

function disablePopupParentNodesOverflow() {
  let parentNode = document.getElementById("popup");
  while ((parentNode = parentNode.parentNode)) {
    if (parentNode.style) {
      const {overflowX, overflowY, overflow} = parentNode.style;
      previousParentNodesOverflowStylesMap.set(parentNode, {
        overflowX,
        overflowY,
        overflow
      });
      parentNode.style.overflow = "hidden";
    }
  }
} 

function restorePopupParentNodesOverflow() {
  let parentNode = document.getElementById("popup");
  while ((parentNode = parentNode.parentNode)) {
    const previousOverflowStyle = previousParentNodesOverflowStylesMap.get(parentNode);
    if (previousOverflowStyle !== undefined) {
      Object.assign(parentNode.style, previousOverflowStyle); 
    }
  }
  previousParentNodesOverflowStylesMap.clear();
}
```

```css
.popup {
  display: none;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: lightgreen;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Creating show/hide popup system -->

<button id="showPopup">
  Show popup
</button>

<button id="hidePopup">
  Hide popup
</button>

<!-- Popup -->

<div class="popup" id="popup">
  <P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
  <P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
  <P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
  <P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
  <P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
  <P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
  <P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
</div>

<!-- Rest of page -->

<P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
<P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
<P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
<P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
<P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
<P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
<P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
<P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
<P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
<P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
<P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
<P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
<P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
<P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
<P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
<P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
<P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
<P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
<P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
<P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
<P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
<P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
<P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
<P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
<P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
<P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
<P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
<P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
<P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
<P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
<P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
<P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
<P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
<P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
<P>lorem ipsum dolor</P> 
<P>lorem ipsum dolor</P>
```

Comment: It has the benefit of showing the user where he can or can not scroll

Comment: Thanks, this does not work however if the scrollable container is not the in parent tree of the popup, then it's scroll is not disabled, e.g. wrap `<!-- Rest of page -->` `<p>` tags in a container of fixed height with `overflow-y:auto`, and it will remain scrollable when the popup is up. But well done on restoring the scrollable state afterwards

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, you can try a different approach. You can check whether the scrolling container of the target element is the body or the popup.

**Example**:

```
function h (evt) {
   var currentElement = evt.target;
   while(currentElement) {
       if(currentElement === document.body) {
           evt.preventDefault();
           break;
       }
       if(currentElement.nodeName === 'POPUP') {
           break;
       }
       currentElement = currentElement.parentNode;
   }
}

window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', h, false);
window.addEventListener('wheel', h, false);
```

**Edit - Another version**:

So from what i understand, there might be multiple nested scrollable elements. To handle this situations, i would use the `Element.scrollWidth` and `Element.scrollHeight` properties. If an element's `scrollWidth`/`scrollHeight` is greater than its `clientWidth`/`clientHeight`, then it's a scrollable element.

I also tried your jsfiddle and it seems to be working fine - maybe I am missing something - more explanation would be useful.

```
function h (evt) {
   var currentElement = evt.target;
   while(currentElement && currentElement !== document.body) {
       if(currentElement.nodeName === 'POPUP' || isScrollable(currentElement)) {
           break;
       }
       currentElement = currentElement.parentNode;
   }

   if(currentElement === document.body || !currentElement) {
       evt.preventDefault();
   }
}

function isScrollable(el) {
    return (el.scrollHeight > el.clientHeight || el.scrollWidth > el.clientWidth);
}

window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', h, false);
window.addEventListener('wheel', h, false);
```

Comment: There could be an scrollable parent between the current element and the body.

Comment: @run_the_race please take a look

Comment: An element could be *not* scrollable even if its scrollHeight > clientHeight, for instance `overflow: clip` is such a case. Also, an element which is `position: fixed` won't scroll its parent even if said parent is scrollable.

Comment: A `DOMMouseScroll` event bubbles up the hierarchy, so the `while` loop offers nothing new functionally, but incurs an operational cost by forcing an () algorithm into (²) performance. If we remove the call to `isScrollable()`—which discriminates poorly and unnecessarily (easier to style non-popups with `overscroll-behavior: none;`)—the rest reduces to the following arrow function equivalent: `h = (evt) => evt.target===document.body ? evt.preventDefault() : undefined`. This won't fully solve the problem, though, without `.stopPropagation()`, and a listener to apply/remove the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired behavior of preventing scrolling on the whole page except for the popup when it is opened, you can modify the event listeners and preventDefault functions. Instead of relying solely on the `evt.target` property, you can check whether the element that triggered the scroll event is inside the popup or not. Here's the updated code:

In the `h` function, check if the target element or any of its parents have the class "scroll" (representing the popup). If it does, allow scrolling; otherwise, prevent the default scroll behavior:

```
function h(evt) {
  const targetElement = evt.target;
  if (!targetElement.closest('.scroll')) {
    evt.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

When you open the popup, make sure to call the disableScrollExcept function and pass the popup element:

```
function dis() {
  let e = document.getElementById('scroll');
  disableScrollExcept(e);
}
```

With these changes, when the popup is open and you try to scroll within it, the scrolling will be allowed. When you attempt to scroll outside the popup, the default scroll behavior will be prevented. This way, you can achieve the desired scrolling behavior.

Comment: Thanks, I think you forgot to post the code for the `disableScrollExcept` function?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is indeed that evt.target will reference the element currently under the mouse pointer, which may not be the one that is scrolling.

One possible solution is to use evt.target to check the scrolling container. To do this, we can use a while loop to go through the parents of the target element until we find the one that allows scrolling. Here's a revised function that does that:

```js
function h(evt) {
    let node = evt.target;
    while (node !== null) {
        if (node === document.querySelector('.popup') && node.scrollHeight > node.clientHeight) {
            return; // Scrolling is within the popup, so we allow it
        }
        node = node.parentNode;
    }
    evt.preventDefault(); // The scrolling is not within the popup, so we prevent it
}
```

In this function, the node.scrollHeight > node.clientHeight check is used to determine whether the element is scrollable. If the scrollHeight (the total height, including the part hidden due to scrolling) is greater than the clientHeight (the visible height), the element is scrollable.

Also, you need to replace .popup with the actual selector of your popup element.

You would add your event listeners just like before:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', h, false)
window.addEventListener('wheel', h, false)
```

Please let me know if this solution works for your case!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but even if an item is scrollable according to your check, once you reach the bottom, the scroll "overflows" and start applying to its parents.